# Does google crawl javascript?

Tags: javascript, seo

Does Google crawl content loaded/created via Javascript?  Traditionally I know the answer was no, but I'm having trouble finding up-to-date sources on this.

Comment: we all use the same search engines. this is not really the type of question we do here, don't you think?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: @ChrisDrappier, this question relates to programming for search engines.  If there's a better place to ask, I'm open to suggestions. =D

Answer (score 1):

Google understands some parts of the code and can render thumbnails of javascript pages, but I would never rely on this for my pages to be indexed.
The best is to create number of html pages just as google webmaster suggests.
Dont forget to put sitemap as well.

Comment: Because google javascript engine will never execute the code like human does, so this way it's not guaranteed that all javascript links will be crawled, because the number of steps on e.g. 3 level complex wizard can make infinite number of possibilites as well it might not work due to human readable code requirement. The answer is to follow google webmaster. Why? Because there is no better way of doing it. Also, javascript is not a way to index links. Google sitemap is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write just one word or it would be "NO", the reason being, a crawler can't execute events like a "mouseover" on every element to change the DOM and wait for ajax responses etc... Think about all the work the crawler would have to simulate to read DOM changes that may or may not happen. This would produce different content for the same URL, so it assumes to never do that so your content appears to be the same from an SEO standpoint. Does that help a little more?

Comment: That's an answer; have a source to back it?