# Google and loading content in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Just a quick question for you all...

I've got a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rbj3h/1/) and just wondering if we load content this way from an external api on load of the page will Google be able to see this information?

Here's the code of the fiddle...

```
<p>Property name <span id="property_name"></span></p>

function propInfo(propertyName) {

    document.getElementById("property_name").innerHTML = propertyName;

}
```

Accessing this api is out of my hands - I'm told the only way to do it currently is via Javascript.

We obviously want our pages to be appearing correctly in Google so any help with this would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does google crawl javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711762/does-google-crawl-javascript) and also [Google Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) and also [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript). -1 for lack of research

Comment: I have actually been researching it and there wasn't a definitive answers so thought you helpful lot here may be able to give your opinions - we are trying to give enough evidence against using it

Comment: Apologies if I came across harshly. The Google Blog I linked to covers this pretty well I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at these guidelines to make sure that Google can access whatever content you load via AJAX - https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

As long as you're compliant with those, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: That's a slightly different thing. Related, but slightly different.

Comment: I did look into the Ajax side of it but they are suggesting we use pure javascript for the calls - we don't really want to do this ideally we would like to get hold of the data server and then push the content out

Answer (score 0):

The only people who can definitively answer this for you are Google.

Matt Cutts [did confirm](http://www.searchnewz.com/seo-interview-with-matt-cutts-2010-03) that Google's crawler does run some content-generating JavaScript and index the result, but I don't think the details of the limits of that have ever been publicly disclosed.